# Redirect `www` to `non-www` EXCEPT if its LetsEncrypt verification

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to make the LetsEncrypt autoSSL crawler to work on my htaccess which is implementing whitelist method.

The crawler can successfully verify my domain as it can access:

```
$ curl -i http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/BEKT19DL9JIG9S5GPP50XAL9ZSPAV54J

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

because my implementation of: (1)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/[A-F0-9]{32}.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /\.well\-known\/acme\-challenge
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule (.*) - [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have this rule to redirect `www` site version to `non-www` version: (2)

```
# Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

So, to handle the crawler trying to verify the `www` of the domain and not getting the 301 redirect, I Implemented the following htaccess rule: (3)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/[A-F0-9]{32}.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /\.well\-known\/acme\-challenge
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule (.*) - [L]
</IfModule>
```

BUT, the crawler is getting `301 permanent redirect` when trying to verify the `www` version

```
$ curl -i http://www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/BEKT19DL9JIG9S5GPP50XAL9ZSPAV54J

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
```

I do not understand why the (2) htaccess rule is still causing the crawler to get `301 redirect`, is there something wrong with my (3) rule?

To summarise, my problem is:

- allow access to hidden directory: /.well-known/acme-challenge/ (only if it is an existing file)
- if accessing it via the `www` version, don't redirect and serve the file (making the HTTP/1.1 status code 200)

Hope somebody can help.

Regards,

Comment: I cannot tell what your final .htaccess rewrite rules look like, whether they are a combination of the three rules you posted or just the third one.  One thing to check would be order of your rewrite rules.  If the www RewriteRule is first, since it matches all patterns, all requests will get the 301 redirect and then check if it matches the other RewriteRules.  You should also look at your use of rewrite flags, a RewriteRule with the L flag will stop processing additional rules if it matches.

Comment: @GracefulRestart I have updated my post to include the full htaccess I have. Its the combination of 3, with the `acme-challenge` rules set first and how come its still getting redirected :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am still not sure what is happening, but it appears rule (1) and (3) are the same RewriteRule with one differing RewriteCond, that does not seem to actually rewrite anything in the end.  I am also not sure the exact behavior of using multiple  checks in the same htaccess file.

At this point the easiest troubleshooting would be to simplify your rewrite rules to help identify what is happening.

Without actually testing, my simplified rewrite rules might look like this (I also cleaned up some backslashes that I did not think needed to be there, I could be wrong though):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[A-F0-9]{32}.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/\.well-known\/acme-challenge
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Again, without testing I read this as:  All request patterns should match both rules, but the rules each have the LAST flag so processing should stop when one matches.  In the rule without any rewriting, if %{HTTP_HOST} starts with www, and one of the three links is present (using OR flag instead of implicit AND) and is an existing file, do not rewrite and stop processing rewrite rules.  If the request does not match any of those conditions, then the second RewriteRule will be processed, if %{HTTP_HOST} starts with www and the connection is not HTTPS, then rewrite to http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} using a 301 redirect and stop processing rewrite rules.

If none of that works and you still cannot figure what Apache is doing, it would be time to enable the RewriteRule debug logs (instructions would be different depending on which version of Apache you are using).

Comment: actually, I just learned that I was supposed to put (1) rule above anything else to make it work. But good work ;)